use java udf in pyspark, raise type exception
Step 1: Define a scala UDF:

import org.apache.spark.sql.api.java.UDF1
import scala.collection.mutable

class GetMidVal extends UDF1[mutable.WrappedArray[Double], Double] {
  override def call(arr: mutable.WrappedArray[Double]): Double = {
    val n = arr.length
    val arr_sorted = arr.sorted
    val mid: Int = (n - 1) / 2
    val mid_mod: Int = mid / 2

    if(mid_mod == 1) {
      val res: Double = arr_sorted.apply(mid)
      res
    } else {
      val res: Double = (arr_sorted.apply(mid) + arr_sorted.apply(mid + 1)) / 2
      res
    }
  }
}

Step 2: Use MyUDF in JavaSpark，no problem
    public void callMidVal(SparkSession spark) {
        spark.udf().register("getMidVal", new GetMidVal(), DataTypes.DoubleType);

        StructType structType = new StructType();
        structType = structType.add("id", DataTypes.StringType, false);
        structType = structType.add("trx_amt", DataTypes.DoubleType, false);

        List<Row> nums = new ArrayList<Row>();
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("001", 3.0));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("001", 8.0));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("001", 10.0));
        nums.add(RowFactory.create("001", 2.0));

        Dataset<Row> df = spark.createDataFrame(nums, structType);

        df.groupBy("id").agg(
                        functions.max("trx_amt"),
                        functions.min("trx_amt"),
                        functions.collect_list("trx_amt").alias("trx_amt_seq")
                ).withColumn("mid_val", functions.expr("getMidVal(trx_amt_seq)"))
                .show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Java Spark SQL basic example")
                .master("local")
                .getOrCreate();

//        new Main().callConcat(spark);
        new Main().callMidVal(spark);
    }

+---+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+
| id|max(trx_amt)|min(trx_amt)|         trx_amt_seq|mid_val|
+---+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+
|001|        10.0|         2.0|[3.0, 8.0, 10.0, ...|    5.5|
+---+------------+------------+--------------------+-------+

Step3: Use MyUDF in PySpark，raise Exception
def call_mid_val():
    spark.udf.registerJavaFunction("getMidVal", "org.spark.udf.GetMidVal")

    data = [
        ("001", 3.0), ("001", 2.3), ("001", 1.5),
        ("001", 4.2), ("001", 9.6),
        ("001", 7.3)
    ]


    df = spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'trx_amt']) \
        .groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("trx_amt").alias("trx_amt_seq"))
    df.show(truncate=False)
    df.printSchema()
    print(df.dtypes)
    print(df.schema)

    spark.createDataFrame(data, ['id', 'trx_amt'])\
        .groupBy("id").agg(F.collect_list("trx_amt").alias("trx_amt_seq"))\
        .select(F.expr("getMidVal(trx_amt_seq)"))\
        .show()

Error Info:
24/06/15 22:17:57 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 3)
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to execute user defined function (UDFRegistration$$Lambda$3116/0x0000000801e57608: (array<double>) => struct<>)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors$.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala:177)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.errors.QueryExecutionErrors.failedExecuteUserDefinedFunctionError(QueryExecutionErrors.scala)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$SpecificUnsafeProjection.apply(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.AggregationIterator.$anonfun$generateResultProjection$5(AggregationIterator.scala:260)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:96)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.aggregate.ObjectAggregationIterator.next(ObjectAggregationIterator.scala:32)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.$anonfun$getByteArrayRdd$1(SparkPlan.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$mapPartitionsInternal$2$adapted(RDD.scala:890)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:365)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:329)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:136)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.$anonfun$run$3(Executor.scala:548)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1504)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:551)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1144)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:642)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1623)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (3.0) of the type (java.lang.Double) cannot be converted to struct<>
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:267)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:241)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:106)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$.$anonfun$createToCatalystConverter$2(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:477)
    ... 18 more

Why return Type is not Double???
my spark version
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.3</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

all info

are you able to upgrade the spark version used?  That version is very old and there have been many upgrades to the pyspark usage since then.
